# Accessing and modifying the model from the attribute directive

Tags: angularjs, events, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Let's say I have a directive `m-list` that listens for a certain event to get its items.

```
$rootScope.$on('certain-event', function (msg) {
    vm.items = msg.data;
});
```

Now I am writing another directive (an attribute directive) that would add functionality to the list, I would name it `m-searchable`. This adds the ability to filter through the list of items and show only items that matches data passed to by another event. Ideally

```
<m-list m-searchable></m-list>
```

And searchable would have something like:

```
$rootScope.$on('search', function (msg) {
    var searchValue = msg.searchValue;
    // update the items of the parent directive
    // like parent.items = matches(searchValue, parent.items)
});
```

Comment: this filter directive looks a lot a the filter [filter][1] :-).[1]: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: yeah, more like the filter directive.

Comment: It is a filter as you can see you can access it from javascript code throught the $filter service, and use it on your function or another method $filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator) Hope this help

Comment: Maybe you can show me how you'll do it :)

Comment: Maybe you can show me how you'll do it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) to filter data.

```
<li data-ng-repeat="item in vm.items | filter:searchInput">
```

I made a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RG3bnsI2U48TUNZhb24M?p=preview) as i would architecture it. Notice that the fake data could come from a service.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but this cannot be the case, as the approach **should** be the *evented* way

Comment: What is preventing you of using an event to load the data?

Comment: I changed the plunker.

Comment: I cannot pass the data like that, .. those codes above are part of the directive, not part of a controller of an app,